# second or third person: addressing a single person in an email to a group

Tags: writing-style, email, third-person

How do I address a single person in an email sent to a group?

We are discussing a project in an email thread that has multiple members.

What is the correct way to address a single sentence to only one of the thread members (although I am still interested in all reading the email and I am still sending to all).

**First try, using second person:**

> "As to your suggestion, John, its advantage is that it dramatically
>   reduces costs while not impacting the customers in that area, but you still 
>   need to work on it and improve it so it passes certification"

**Second try, using third person:**

> "As to John's suggestion, its advantage is that it dramatically reduces
>   costs while not impacting the customers in that area, but he still needs to work on it and improve it so it passes certification"

Is there a right way to do it, or is it a just an issue of preferences and style?

Comment: Yes, I think your question is about personal style and preference. I always used "To John, as to your suggestion... you still needs to work...", To Jane, as to your suggestion, you still needs to work...", To Tom, as to you suggestion, you still ...". It creates a paragraph for an addressed person to pay extra attention to". Again, it was my style.

Comment: A way easier solution to this problem isn't really personal style, but something that was adapted from chat programs and widely used in emails now as well - @ -ing someone.

Just go with @John. More formally would be To John. Indicates third person.

Answer (score 0):

If the members of the group know of their belonging to the group, precede the parts of the e-letter pertinent to them all with "GROUP:". For parts of the e-letter pertinent only to selected individuals, precede such parts with the names -- e.g., "Mr. Adams, Ms. Kozłowska:". One could also use formulæ such as "GROUP, except Mr. Adams:". If the culture of the firm permits, less formality might be in order, too.